# Turbo C++ time resolution up to milliseconds

Tags: c++, timing, turbo-c++

The clock_t implications in time.h released with Turbo C++ v1.01 are good only up to 0.0545XX seconds, meaning any timing I want to do with higher precision is impossible with that library.

I was wondering if anyone knew a good library or method available to elder TurboC++ that I could use instead of time.h calls for better precision?

Comment: You need to say what operating system you're running under. If you're running a DOS application in a Windows 'dos-box', you'll find the timing dismally bad, whatever facilities your language/libraries offer.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the ancient Turbo C++ for DOS? I recognise that number as the ~1/18th of a second of the default DOS performance timer.

You can speed up the timer, but you'll have to write an interrupt routine that intercepts that timer and only passes on some of the interrupts. Or you'll get strange behavior from other parts of DOS. I have code for this somewhere which I may be able to dig out.

Comment: If the OP just needs to measure short times, he can do it by reading the timer registers directly (accounting correctly for wrapping).  That way one doesn't need to mess around with ISRs.

Answer (score -1):

Use Windows QueryPerformanceCounter (and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Not from Turbo C.  They are 32-bit API functions.